# How to make setInterval method have only one instance running

Tags: javascript, html

I have a button that, when clicked, starts a timer and decreases the integer by 1 per second.
However, if the button is clicked multiple times, the integer decreases by a lot more than 1 per second, due to setInterval being called multiple times.

How do I make it so that, even though the button is clicked multiple times, the timer only goes down by 1 each second (I do not want to disable the button).

```
var time = document.getElementById("time");
document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  var decreaseTime = setInterval(() => {
            if (time.textContent != 0) {
                time.innerHTML = time.textContent - 1;
            }
        }, 1000);

   if (time.textContent == 0) {
            clearInterval(decreaseTime);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define your decreaseTime variable in a higher scope and then check if it exists prior to defining your interval.  For instance:

```
var time = document.getElementById("time");
decreaseTime = undefined;
document.getElementById("Btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  if(!decreaseTime){
    decreaseTime = setInterval(() => {
      if (time.textContent != 0) {
        time.innerHTML = time.textContent - 1;
      }
    }, 1000);

    if (time.textContent == 0) {
      clearInterval(decreaseTime);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The first semicolon should be replaced by comma.